# disable blueprintjs open dialog animation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, blueprintjs

I have a blueprintjs dialog :

```
<BP.Dialog iconName="application" isOpen={this.state.fieldformopen} ...>
```

When the state fieldformopen changes, the dialog appear. But it appears with a growing animation. This is a problem since the dialog is quite full of things, and the animation is slow and discontinued.

I don't see any way of disabling the animation. The fields transitionDuration and transitionName are set only when changing css.

Thanks for any information to disable the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to the Dialog component:

`style={{ transition: 'none' }}`

So your component would look like:

```
<Dialog
    style={{ transition: 'none' }} >
```

This removes the growing animation, but still keeps the more subtle fade animation.

Comment: perfect ! thats works exactly as expected. thanks a lot